# affect html a on a:hover from same div

Tags: javascript

i have no knowledge in javascript and the knowledge i have in css is not enough to figure it out, if it can be done ..

i have  a div with five a's in it:

```
<div>
    <a>1</a>
    <a>2</a>
    <a>3</a>
    <a>4</a>
    <a>5</a>
</div>
```

How can i write something in javascript that would do something like:

on a:hover change the color of the a's from the right of the a hovered

for example if all a's are black and if i hover a2 ... then turn a3, a4 and a5 to white, while a1 and a2 remain black

thanks for any links or feedback

Comment: Is using jQuery an option or do you only want to use plain JavaScript?

Comment: sure it is, looks way easier .. any cons of using jquery instead of js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### A plain JavaScript method -- doesn't utilize jQuery.

#### Update:

[Here is a demonstration.](http://jsfiddle.net/Vq8f6/4/)

Here's a function that iterates over the `<a>` inside `<div>` looking for the one clicked. All subsequent links are colored white.

```
function colorLinks(node) {
  // Gets the parent div
  var parentDiv = node.parentNode;
  // And get a list of all the links contained in the div
  var aLinks = parentDiv.getElementsByTagName("a");
  var nLinks = aLinks.length;
  var passed = false;

  // Loop over all the links
  for (var i=0; i<nLinks; i++) {
     // Set colors of the links if the loop has already passed the calling node
     if (passed) {
       aLinks[i].style.color = "white";
       // Note: instead of style.color, could set a CSS class afterHover
       // and setup the colors in CSS (probably better)
       // aLinks[i].className = "afterHover";
     }
     else {
       aLinks[i].style.color = "black";
       // Note: instead of style.color, could set a CSS class beforeHover
       // aLinks[i].className = "beforeHover";
     }

     // Set a flag when the hovered node was passed in our loop
     if (aLinks[i] == node) {
       passed = true;
     }
  }
}

function unColorLinks(node) {
  var aLinks = node.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (var i=0; i<aLinks.length; i++) {
     aLinks[i].style.color = "black";
  }
}
<div>
    <a onmouseover='colorLinks(this);' onmouseout='unColorLinks(this);'>1</a>
    <a onmouseover='colorLinks(this);' onmouseout='unColorLinks(this);''>2</a>
    <a onmouseover='colorLinks(this);' onmouseout='unColorLinks(this);'>3</a>
    <a onmouseover='colorLinks(this);' onmouseout='unColorLinks(this);'>4</a>
    <a onmouseover='colorLinks(this);' onmouseout='unColorLinks(this);'>5</a>
</div>
```

**Note**: Inline `onmouseover` attributes aren't the best way of binding these events, but are certainly the easiest to get started.

Comment: Someone who does not know much js, does not know much css and wants to copy and paste this code **better off using jquery**.

Comment: @Aliostad Nobody's claiming plain JavaScript is the better solution for this particular problem - anything you can do with jQuery, you can do with plain JS although sometimes it is orders of magnitude more difficult to achieve. This isn't one of those times.

Comment: nice, though when the user moves the mouse away from the 'a' then the right a's should turn back to black
i accept the answer as this is probably an easy hack to your script above ... later edit: it looks like i cannot accept both answers?

Comment: @user1023857 Yep, only one answer can be accepted.  I added a function to turn the links back to black `onmouseout`.

Comment: cool, i accept yours since i initially asked for javascript, cheers!

Comment: @user1023857 To be clear in case you're unfamilar, jQuery is a library that sits on top of JavaScript, and jQuery is itself implemented in JavaScript to make things like this quite a lot easier.  So accept and use whatever solution makes things work best for you.

Comment: yes, i know that, but if i want to get to learn jquery i need to start with java script ... what does this do more exactly **if (passed && aLinks[i] != node)** ... passed && aLinks[i] could be true or false but how do you compare it with node - does node have a boolean value ? ... by the way is there any built-in function or something that when it switches to white to fade - like a css transition ?

Comment: @user1023857 Excellent that you're taking the time to learn JS without diving directly into jQuery. It's a nuanced and powerful language.  I refactored the code above to fix that weird statement you inquired about. `passed` is a boolean set to `true` when the node that was hovered was encountered in the for loop.  So the statement basically said _if the loop has already passed the calling node, and aLinks[i] (the current loop iteration is not that node, turn it white._  ....

Comment: ... However, it makes more sense to set the colors first _before_ changing the `passed` flag to `true` for the calling node (which was passed to the function with `this` in the HTML).  That way, the calling node stays black no matter what and subsequent loop iterations are white since the flag gets set at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery is easy:

```
$("a").hover(
    function(){
        $(this).nextAll().css("color", "#FFF");
    },
     function(){
         $("a").css("color", "#000");
     }
);​
```

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vXAWJ/3/).

Comment: great this is what I want!! i need to learn some javascript then move onto jquery coz that looks easy!